# I have more than one Form in the Solution, how to change the starting Form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have more than 1 forms in solution, how to make required form as default to run?

Apart from the option available in project by default Program.cs to change:

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

Is there any other method so that I do not have to open each and every time the Program.cs file to change the startup form.?

Comment: *"by default Program.cs to change Application.Run(new Form1());"* - That's exactly how one specifies which form to open when running the application.  Is this not working for you in some way?  *"so that I do not have to open each and every time the program.cs file"* - How often do you need to change your startup form for this application?  It's not clear to me what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Other methods like what? Do you have a suggestion for a better UX here, which keeps the flexibility that is required for configuring the startup?

Comment: @David Since I am practising with many forms having different logic so to try them I need to run the required form, it is not an application

Comment: @MPC: As part of such practice, you might try building a "startup form" which itself is sort of a menu/catalog/etc. of all of the disparate "forms" in your application, allowing the user to select which one to launch.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be able to change the startup form, without having to modify `Program.cs` and rebuilding your application, you can do the following:

Put the information which form to launch in a configuration file (in any format e.g. json, ini file, plain txt file).
You'll also need a method to load and parse this config file. Let's say you have a class `Config` with the parsed configuration, and a field like `WhichForm` identifying the form you want to launch.

Then change the current `Program.cs` from:

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

To something like:

```
Config cfg = LoadConfig();

// Decide which form to use:
Form theForm = null;
switch (cfg.WhichForm) // assuming Config.WhichForm is a FormType enum
{
    case FormType.F1 : theForm = new Form1(); break;
    case FormType.F2 : theForm = new Form2(); break;
    default : // handle error
}

// Launch the selected form:
Debug.Assert(theForm != null);
Application.Run(theForm);
```

Now you don't have to build your project to change the startup form - just change the config file and restart the application.

Comment: I am not able to understand can you bit explain with example whatever is mentioned

Comment: What exactly is not clear ? Do you know about configuration files and their usage ? The rest is written above quite explictly.

Comment: Added some more info in my answer.

Comment: If you want to start with a simple implementation, you can simply use a txt file with one number in it. If it is 1 - launch Form1 etc.

Comment: How opening the config/text file and specifying the startup form, is easier than opening Program.cs and modifying startup form?

Comment: @RezaAghaei It enables to change the config without rebuilding the application. Other than that I'm not sure what can help the OP.